# "row is too big (...) maximum size 8160" when running "grant connect on database"

Tags: postgresql

I'm facing weird issue with postgres 11.

I'm creating a bunch of users and then assigning them some roles but also letting them to connect to certain database.

After successfully creating 2478 roles when I try to create new user I get this error:

```sql
db=# create user foo;
CREATE ROLE
db=# grant connect on database db to foo;
ERROR:  row is too big: size 8168, maximum size 8160
```

Same error shows up in db log.

I checked if db volume is not running out of space, there is still 1T to spare there...

I can't imagine postgres trying to insert more than 8k when running simple grant...?

---

edit:

It seems there was similar question asked already (usage privileges on schema):

[ERROR: row is too big: size 8168, maximum size 8164](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50016654/error-row-is-too-big-size-8168-maximum-size-8164)

So the solution would be to create one role, say `connect_to_my_db` and grant connect to that role, and then instead of running `GRANT connect` to each user do `GRANT connect_to_my_db`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You found the solution yourself, let me add an explanation of the cause of the error:

Each table row is stored in one of the 8KB blocks of the table, so that is its size limit.

Normal tables have a *TOAST table*, where long attributes can be stored out-of-line. This allows PostgreSQL to store very long rows.

Now system catalog tables do not have TOAST tables, so rows are limited to 8KB size.

The *access control list* of an object is stored in the object's catalog, so many permissions on a table can exceed the limit.

Be glad — if you had to manage permissions for thousands of users individually, you'd end up in DBA hell anyway.